# Drawing stroked UIBezierPath in drawRect not showing up

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I have a shape which has a few UIBezierPaths which I am trying to draw in my view and they aren't showing up. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
// Function to perform custom drawing.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    for (Stroke* stroke in letter.strokes)
    {
        if (letter.strokes[letter.currentStroke] == stroke)
        {
            [stroke.path stroke];
        }
        else
        {
            [stroke.path strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.5f];
        }
        [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:stroke.path.bounds];
    }
}
```

New code which also isn't working:

```
for (Stroke* stroke in letter.strokes)
    {
        UIBezierPath* path = stroke.path;

        [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];

        [[UIColor redColor] setFill];

        CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        CGContextSaveGState(currentContext);

        CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 50, 50);

        path.lineWidth = 5;

        if (letter.strokes[letter.currentStroke] == stroke)
        {
            [path fill];
            [path stroke];
        }
        else
        {
            [stroke.path strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.5f];
        }
        [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:stroke.path.bounds];

        CGContextRestoreGState(currentContext);
    }
```

Comment: You're sure that `letter.strokes` is non-0?

Comment: Also, what happens when you comment out the `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` call?

Comment: setNeedsDisplayInRect didn't change anything and I walked through it in the debugger and it execute at least once. Just nothing shows up in the view.

Comment: i think you need to set a stroke color to the context.

Comment: I tried that to no avail, you can see my new attempt above.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually fixed it by attaching this view and my other one to a view controller and layering them properly.